# Elasticsearch not able to search for term with a slash / in it

Tags: magento2.3, elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch and Elasticsearch not able to search for term with a slash / in it . This issue is solved on version 2.4 and what i am using is version 2.3.5 . I don't plan an upgrade in near future. What kind of workaround would you suggest for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to Magento's workaround in 2.4 to apply to your current version

You can find more here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/25110#issuecomment-707670529